# Транслировать строку из c# в php

Tags: php, c#

```
  byte[] hashedData = hmacGenerator.ComputeHash(tarrrr);
        byte[] codeArray = new byte[5];
        try
        {
            byte b = (byte)(hashedData[19] & 0xF);
            int Point = (hashedData[b] & 0x7F) << 24 | (hashedData[b + 1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (hashedData[b + 2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (hashedData[b + 3] & 0xFF);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                codeArray[i] = CodeTranslations[Point % CodeTranslations.Length];
                Point /= CodeTranslations.Length;
            }
        }
```

Собственно интересует как данная строка будет выглядеть в PHP.
Оригинал в C#

Comment: немного непонятно, что Вы имеете ввиду

Comment: сложновато будет конвертнуть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из предположения, что ваш `hmacGenerator` это SHA1 хеш (по длине в 20 байт подходит), получается так:

```
  $hashedData=sha1($tarrrr,true);
  $b=ord($hashedData[19]) & 0xF;
  $Point=unpack("N",substr($hashedData,$b,4))[1] & 0x7FFFFFFF;

  $arrLen=count($CodeTranslations);
  $codeArray="";
  for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++):
    $codeArray .= chr($CodeTranslations[$Point % $arrLen]);
    $Point = (int)($Point/$arrLen);
  endfor;
```